# Telegraf: what's the difference between a field and a tag in a metric?

Tags: telegraf

Telegraf offers a rich set of filters to manipulate metrics:

Here are a few examples:

- you can whitelist or blacklist tags
- you can drop a metric ("measurement") by their name
- you can also whitelist or blacklist a field.

(see: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md for the complete list)

However, I'm not sure how field differs from a tag. When should I use tagexclude and when should I use fielddrop?

Answer (score 2):

Tags are indexed / Fields are not

Tag keys and values can ONLY be strings.

Fields can be other data types.

This means that queries on tags are faster and that tags are ideal for storing commonly-queried metadata.

Using too many tags with unqiue values can lead to high cardinality problems